# Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)

Tags: lubuntu, software-center, dpkg, dropbox, lock

I tried to install dropbox over the software center but it froze while applying changes. 
I then forced the unresponsive software center to close and killed the ongoing process. Even after rebooting it wont let me download or delete any software from the software center, but instead freeze.
Various other proposed solutions concerning similar problems led to it telling me that I had to run:    sudo dpkg --configure -a
because the dpkg was busy.

If I run this command, dropbox starts to download but as soon as it reaches 100% becomes inactive even though clearly the process is ongoing as it warns me when I close the terminal.
Other advice led to the message in the title.

I am using Lubuntu and just recently migrated to Linux.
Any help would be greatly appreciated and please do not refrain from telling me if this isnt the correct forum.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that some other window might be having the lock . Close all the window and retry , if it doesn't help , reboot.

Installing from terminal:

32-bit:

`cd ~ && wget -O - "https://www.dropbox.com/download?plat=lnx.x86" | tar xzf -`

64-bit:

`cd ~ && wget -O - "https://www.dropbox.com/download?plat=lnx.x86_64" | tar xzf -`

Next, run the Dropbox daemon from the newly created .dropbox-dist folder.

`~/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd`

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, you mean to say close all windows and then retry the dpkg --configure -a ?

Comment: No , reinstall dropbox using command line

Comment: I've edited my ans @MrRoCkXd

Comment: Thanks to your command I can now open dropbox using the command youve given me, but only this way: Trying to open it by clicking on the icon will ask me for the permission by the superuser and but not open when I enter the password.

Comment: This is the smaller problem though. I tried downloading geogebra over the software center and as anticipated it freezes. Is it possible that I have now successfully downloaded dropbox despite the fact that the root of the problem - the fact that my software center  is ''broken'' - is still there??

Comment: Also the software center is very unresponsive in general, so I would like to reinstall it , but this is not possible because the dpkg is busy as mentioned above